# Can't connect Outlet

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, outlet

I don't know what happen with my xcode. Im my controller view only have 3 outlets, but interface builder found 5 outlets. My app always crash in runtime.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove all outlet connection and connect again. May be some outlets you deleted but still exist in Interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Problem caused by previously setted outlet been deleted improperly. You can easily fix this problem by deleting invalid outlet from the storyBoard and also, I can see another issue from your screenshot.You have a  **breakPoint** running on your namePromotionalLabel.Hope this help...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

1. Remove all connections from button
2. Add all connections again, after that your app shouldn't show SIGNAL SIGABRT(which I think it does) anymore

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the outlets from the Outlet section in the above screenshot and then try again to draw and outlet. 
if still it cause a problem then create a new swift controller file for that view controller and assign the class to that view controller

Answer (score 0):

I think this is so basic but almost people don't mention this. 
The problem is view outlet have to connect to main view too. 
Almost cases, it's connected automatically.